# Centered span text gets squished when div becomes too small

Tags: html, css

I have this span text centered above a div so that when the div changes width, it stays in the center of the div. However, when the div width becomes too small, the text gets squished and isn't all on one line. I want the text to stay all on one line no matter how small the with of the div.

What I want (width: 150px):
[image]

What I don't want (width < 145px) text begins to squish onto multiple lines:
[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.div1brother {
  position: relative;
  border-left: 0.01px solid black;
  border-right: 0.01px solid black;
  border-top: 0.01px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.div1brother span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  right: 15%;
  top: -15px;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1brother">
    <span>Cutter O.D. = 25</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add this property to span :-   .div1brother span {white-space: nowrap;}

Comment: @ShahilMishra, it doesn't work, as it doesn't necessarily align that element to center, it just ensures that the element is not wrapped

Comment: What do you want to happen when there is not enough space - e.g. the font size decreases or...?

Comment: I want the font size to stay the same, but everything be on one single line

Answer (score 0):

It varies to which the `div` with absolute position is relative. In your case, it's relative to its parent and hence it takes max-width as its parent's.

##### Alternative:

Let the `span` element be positioned absolute, relative to its grandparent.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;

  ...
}
```

and set its appropriate properties to the `span` element

```css
.div1brother span {
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Now, the wrap state of the `span` element doesn't depend on the width of its parent `div` at all, as its absolute position is relative to its grandparent which is the main container

---

Below is an example with the parent width of `40px`

```css
.container {
  /* relative position here */
  position: relative;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.div1brother {
  border-left: 0.01px solid black;
  border-right: 0.01px solid black;
  border-top: 0.01px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.div1brother span {
  position: absolute;

  /* new properties start */
  top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: yellow;
  /* new properties end */

  display: block;
  padding-left: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1brother">
    <span>Cutter O.D. = 25</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update 13 august 2022**

For me the question was not correctly formulated, there is no mentioned that the problem is the fact that the text is not centered. You could have simply added a comment instead of a negative answer feedback.

Anyway, here is a new update of the **css** using the classic approach
of centering absolute elements.

```
width:100%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -50%;
```

---

**12 august 2022**

I think it's enough to use
`white-space: nowrap;` for the span element.

Unfortunately the `position: absolute` will make the element to not be centered in a proper way.

I've set the **.div1brother** to `100px` to do the code snippet test

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.div1brother {
  position: relative;
  border-left: 0.01px solid black;
  border-right: 0.01px solid black;
  border-top: 0.01px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.div1brother span {
  position: absolute;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-50%;
  top: -15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  /* don't break on new line */
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1brother">
    <span>Cutter O.D. = 25</span>
  </div>
</div>
```